# search result in the output of powershell

Tags: .net, linq, powershell, winapi, console-application

I'm going to use a lot of powershell sentences with different output formats. And I only need few data of all the output in a console application (really is going to a windows application) and I thought to chatch the data using linq, because with Trim is going to be very caothict.

Any Idea, like pass the output to a text file, and use linq with this text file,  but this is goint to be less effective.

For example
How I distinct the output related with any kind of window in this little script using linq or another trick

```
#
# Script.ps1
#
param( [string]$strComputer = ".")

Get-Process | 
    Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} |
    Select-Object MainWindowTitle |
    Out-String -stream
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I think he is trying to rewrite this PowerShell script in C# with LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basicaly the search facility involve the [select-string cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)

As it is hard to tell what your trying to do, here are  some samples

```
$results=Get-Process | 
    Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} |
    Select-Object MainWindowTitle |
    Out-String -stream
$results |select-string "notepad" #process containing the word notepad
$results |select-string "\d{2}"  #process with 2 digits
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a partial solution. I think that from here I can continue by myself.
I will investigate more about select-string